# How to fix "Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent" in R (caret) with 'knnImpute'

Tags: r, r-caret

I am new to the caret package (generally to machine learning with r and caret). I use a publicly available dataset from Seattle, from which I want to predict the class of future incoming requests (by classification).

First I make a 80/20 split on my dataset. There are some NA's in the data which I want tom impute by using caret's knnImpute functionality. After quite some runtime, I get the following error message:

```
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

What am I doing wrong, how can I fix this?

There are more posts on this error. Unfortunately I did not find a suitable solution that helped me with my problem...

My dataset (v1.0) looks like the following:

```
> dataset %>% str()
Classes ‘spec_tbl_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    170657 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ request_type   : Factor w/ 29 levels "Abandoned_Vehicle",..: 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
 $ city_department: Factor w/ 8 levels "Center","City_Light",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ neighborhood   : Factor w/ 91 levels "Adams","Alki",..: 1 1 4 4 10 13 21 21 21 24 ...
 $ weekday        : Ord.factor w/ 7 levels "So"<"Mo"<"Di"<..: 5 2 2 5 1 3 6 4 4 2 ...
 $ month          : Ord.factor w/ 12 levels "Jän"<"Feb"<"Mär"<..: 4 6 1 3 4 3 2 4 7 5 ...
 $ cal_week       : num  15 23 2 10 17 10 6 16 29 21 ...
 $ holiday        : Factor w/ 2 levels "noholiday","holiday": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ businessday    : Factor w/ 2 levels "businessday",..: 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ goodfriday     : Factor w/ 2 levels "nogoodfriday",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

```
> dataset %>% skim()
Skim summary statistics
 n obs: 170657 
 n variables: 9 

── Variable type:factor ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
        variable missing complete      n n_unique                                     top_counts ordered
     businessday       0   170657 170657        2                 bus: 136087, nob: 34570, NA: 0   FALSE
 city_department       0   170657 170657        8 Pol: 54916, Pub: 38171, Dep: 34712, Fin: 25471   FALSE
      goodfriday       0   170657 170657        2                   nog: 170140, goo: 517, NA: 0   FALSE
         holiday       0   170657 170657        2                  noh: 167514, hol: 3143, NA: 0   FALSE
           month       0   170657 170657       12 Aug: 15247, Okt: 14807, Sep: 14785, Mär: 14781    TRUE
    neighborhood    6447   164210 170657       91      NA: 6447, Bro: 4975, Uni: 3941, Wal: 3919   FALSE
    request_type       0   170657 170657       29 Aba: 34478, Cus: 22275, Ill: 22033, Par: 16521   FALSE
         weekday       0   170657 170657        7     Di: 28972, Mi: 28734, Mo: 28721, Do: 27298    TRUE

── Variable type:numeric ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 variable missing complete      n  mean    sd p0 p25 p50 p75 p100     hist
 cal_week       0   170657 170657 26.52 14.78  1  14  27  39   53 ▇▇▇▇▇▇▆▆
```

My split code:

```
set.seed(100)

split <- createDataPartition(dataset$request_type, p=0.8, list=FALSE)

train <- dataset[split,]
train_x = train[, 2:8]
train_y = train$request_type

test <- dataset[-split,]
test_x = test[, 2:8]
test_y = test$request_type
```

My imputation code:

```
model.preprocessed.imputed <- preProcess(train, method='knnImpute')
model.preprocessed.imputed

train <- predict(model.preprocessed.imputed, newdata = train)
```

Wenn running the prediction, I get the error message

```
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

From traceback I get the following info:

```
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
3. `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = miss_names)
2. predict.preProcess(PreProcess.MissingDatamodel, newdata = train)
1. predict(PreProcess.MissingDatamodel, newdata = train)
```

**Update 2nd April 2019**

The first version of my dataset (v1.0) showed me a mixed class:

```
> dataset %>% str()
Classes ‘spec_tbl_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    170657 obs. of  9 variables:
```

Since I found some posts indicating that caret might react strange to tibbles, I tried to convert my dataset to a common data frame (v1.1):

```
dataset <- as.data.frame(dataset)
dataset %>% str()
'data.frame':   170657 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ request_type   : Factor w/ 29 levels "Abandoned.Vehicle",..: 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
 $ city_department: Factor w/ 8 levels "Center","City.Light",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ neighborhood   : Factor w/ 91 levels "Adams","Alki",..: 1 1 4 4 10 13 21 21 21 24 ...
 $ weekday        : Ord.factor w/ 7 levels "So"<"Mo"<"Di"<..: 5 2 2 5 1 3 6 4 4 2 ...
 $ month          : Ord.factor w/ 12 levels "Jän"<"Feb"<"Mär"<..: 4 6 1 3 4 3 2 4 7 5 ...
 $ cal_week       : num  15 23 2 10 17 10 6 16 29 21 ...
 $ holiday        : Factor w/ 2 levels "noholiday","holiday": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ businessday    : Factor w/ 2 levels "businessday",..: 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ goodfriday     : Factor w/ 2 levels "nogoodfriday",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

```
dataset %>% skim()
Skim summary statistics
 n obs: 170657 
 n variables: 9 

── Variable type:factor ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
        variable missing complete      n n_unique                                     top_counts ordered
     businessday       0   170657 170657        2                 bus: 136087, nob: 34570, NA: 0   FALSE
 city_department       0   170657 170657        8 Pol: 54916, Pub: 38171, Dep: 34712, Fin: 25471   FALSE
      goodfriday       0   170657 170657        2                   nog: 170140, goo: 517, NA: 0   FALSE
         holiday       0   170657 170657        2                  noh: 167514, hol: 3143, NA: 0   FALSE
           month       0   170657 170657       12 Aug: 15247, Okt: 14807, Sep: 14785, Mär: 14781    TRUE
    neighborhood    6447   164210 170657       91      NA: 6447, Bro: 4975, Uni: 3941, Wal: 3919   FALSE
    request_type       0   170657 170657       29 Aba: 34478, Cus: 22275, Ill: 22033, Par: 16521   FALSE
         weekday       0   170657 170657        7     Di: 28972, Mi: 28734, Mo: 28721, Do: 27298    TRUE

── Variable type:numeric ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 variable missing complete      n  mean    sd p0 p25 p50 p75 p100     hist
 cal_week       0   170657 170657 26.52 14.78  1  14  27  39   53 ▇▇▇▇▇▇▆▆
```

Although being of class data.frame only now, it did not fix my issue.

Comment: Where can we find the dataset? Could you add a `dput` of it?

Comment: the error can be replicated with just the first 200 rows of the data set. Its interesting that if one omits the first 100 rows then no error occurs when 100:5000 rows used, but when 100:10000 the error is present. I still haven't found the exact source of the problem.

Comment: I also had the gut feeling that it somehow has to do with my dataset object. During my further search for a solution online, I also found indicators that the caret functions seem to be not 100% compatible with tibbles. So I tried to convert my dataset to a data.frame with "dataset <- as.data.frame(dataset)". Unfortunately, this also did not solve the issue. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the root of my problems:

I initially used tidyverse's readr::read_csv(), which somehow gave me a data object with weird behavior (as missuse also stated in the comments - thanks for your input):

```
dataset <- read_csv("data/DataSet.csv") %>% clean_names()
```

After using read.csv(), I did not have NA's in my dataset anymore and all of caret's functions suddenly work with my data:

```
dataset <- read.csv("data/DataSet.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% clean_names()
```

Perhaps this finding can be helpful for somebody else too since I wasted a huge amount of time looking for error messages that resulted from a faulty dataset object.

**UPDATE**

Now I know why there were no NA's anmymore. I figured out that read.csv() reads the NA's but makes them empty strings ("") while read_csv() explicitly makes them NA's. I simply transformed the NA's into a factor too ("missing"), so I do not have to remove data and risk losing Information.